# How to remove views saved by :mkview

Tags: vimrc, autocmd

I use `:mkview` to save folders in vim:

```
autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview
```

but how to delete currently saved views? I comment out those two lines from vimrc but I fond that I can still use `:loadview` to load the previous view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim saves views in a folder defined by the `:h 'viewdir'` option.

By default, it's `~/.vim/view` on unix systems.

You can browse the directory and delete the relevant view file.

Also, depending on your problem, you might want to change the `:h 'viewoptions'` (e.g. `set viewoptions-=options`).

Comment: Thank you, I just had a further question, does ```hi``` command count as options? e.g. ```:hi ColorColumn ctermbg=240```,
I searched online for vim options and all are talking about ```:set``` command...

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to save your highlight for reuse is to put it in your `vimrc` (or other vimscript file). It seems you've encountered a X/Y problem. I suggest you post a question about what you are trying to achieve rather than how to solve a problem that might not be relevant for you.

Comment: @JiangYuanhao [comments are for clarifications and critiques](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); if you have a new question, just ask ([ask])